# List<T>.RemoveAll() efficiency / compiler optimisation

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, compiler-optimization

Regarding efficiency, does anyone know if the compiler is clever enough to ***not*** create the array containing `1, 3, 5` for each iteration of the loop in the following code?

```
var foo = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
foo.RemoveAll(i => new[] { 1, 3, 5 }.Contains(i));
```

I prefer it for readability, but not at the sake of performance.

Comment: try for your self https://sharplab.io/

Comment: @MichaelRandall Great site. You should write an answer for this with an short example. This is interesseting for everybody, i think.

Comment: I'm really surprised but it looks like it does actually create a new instance of the 3 item array for each iteration inside the method `internal bool <M>b__0_0(int i)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is no it doesn't optimize out the allocation of the array

Basically, every time the predicate is called, it checks against the compiler generated class and initializes a new array to call the `Contains` (as you can see [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgHgbALAPgAgBgARwIwG4CwAoRLVRa7JoB0AMgJYB2AjkXAMwoBMSAwkgN45J8rM4UJAFkAFAEpuvfrIBuAQwBOSAGYB7dUgC8SagFMA7kioBnAC4AeGuYB83JKgA0SFi8YuoLgKxIAvkSyshrqpABK+gC26nL6AIIANglilDr2BoYA2gC6Ds5IHki+fqTs6tTmCjSmKRISgfx+OH5AA==))

```
private sealed class <>c
{
    public static readonly <>c <>9 = new <>c();

    public static Predicate<int> <>9__0_0;

    internal bool <M>b__0_0(int i)
    {
        // bam!
        int[] obj = new int[3];
        RuntimeHelpers.InitializeArray(obj, (RuntimeFieldHandle)/*OpCode not supported: LdMemberToken*/);
        return Enumerable.Contains(obj, i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As @Michael Randall already wrote, it looks like it is not possible.

I agree, that your questioned code is nicely readable, having the list in the RemoveAll method. But to have the instance only once, I have three ideas of doing it:

```
int[] a = null;
foo.RemoveAll(i => (a ?? (a = new[] { 1, 3, 5 })).Contains(i));
```

This is actually yours, with little un-beatuness of needing an external variable.

```
 foo = foo.Except(new[] { 1, 3, 5 }).ToList();
```

That's actually pretty nice solution using Linq.

```
 new List<int>{1, 3, 5}.ForEach(x => foo.Remove(x));


 new[] {1, 3, 5}.Iterate(x => foo.Remove(x));
```

This is something I'd do. In neary all of my code I have my Extension method "Iterate" to avoid the need of foreach. And also, i dont want to "toList" everything all the time to make a .ForEach(..)

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static void Iterate<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Action<TSource> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            action.Invoke(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware, `RemoveAll` performs vastly better that multiple calls to `Remove`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the compiler is not that smart, we must outsmart him.

```
var foo = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var bar = new HashSet<int>() { 1, 3, 5 };
foo.RemoveAll(i => bar.Contains(i));
```

Comment: A hash set of 3 entries will surely not perform better, it would arguably (I have not measured) perform worse.

Comment: @Sefe While there is probably a difference between the hash set and the array, I think the point of this answer was to create `bar` *outside* of the anonymous function so that's it's created only once and to avoid the creation overhead.

Comment: @Sefe what you say is true, but I think that the OP provided a trivial example just to illustrate a point. In a real world scenario the lists will be probably longer than that.